# HtmlEditor in AjaxControlToolkit

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using HtmlEditor from AjaxControlToolkit.

how can I get the text that I type in the editor into a div. I want to show whatever is typed as a preview message. I do not want to use the preview that comes with the HtmlEditor.

I am using a normal html button to do preview again.

Can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

This javascript will get the contents of the editor:

```
function getEditorText() {
    var editor = $find('myHTMLEditor');

    return editor.get_content();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.
where and how should I call this getEditorText()

Comment: I would call it on click of a button to show you the preview.

Comment: how do I assign the function return value to a label using jquery

Comment: I get an error saying null is null or not an object. I am stuck. Please help :(

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following, add a div and inside of it add the following

and then add an a tag with an id, and the runat=server

and after that you can insert the text that is in the htmleditor using the following code

string content = HtmlEditorExtender1.Content;
textResult.InnerText = content

I hope this help you

Comment: Can you please add a snippet for your answer?